# android canvas.drawBitmap somehow shows up behind the view

Tags: android

i called canvas.drawBitmap to draw an image, but somehow it's showing up behind/underneath the custom view (or it's background).  can someone explain this?  thanks.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped. Since that has solved your problem, could you click on the tickmark next to my answer? That marks it as the "Accepted answer", telling people this problem has been solved. It's also a good idea to go through and do that on your other questions - currently it shows that you haven't accepted *any* answers, and you might find people less willing to help in the future. Have a look at the FAQ for more detail about the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which you draw things matters when dealing with canvases. For example,

```
canvas.drawBitmap(redCircle, 0, 0, null);    
canvas.drawBitmap(blueSquare, 0, 0, null);
```

will draw the blueSquare on top of the redCircle. If the square is bigger or doesn't have any transparency, the circle might be entirely hidden. Unfortunately, I can't be more specific than that unless you give a bit more information about your specific problem. (Edit the question to provide the code, and leave a comment saying you've done it.)